# Need help interpreting a printer PS label

Tags: power-supply

I have an HP OfficeJet 8600 that won't power up.  First it wouldn't turn off, but after doing a standard partial reset described on several websites, it now refuses to turn on.  Took the CMOS battery out, verified it was good with a multi-meter, and had it out a good 45 minutes, so anything that can be reset/cleared by removing it for a few minutes definitely was.

Took the power supply out to meter it, and that's where my confusion begins.  If you look at the label on the PS in the attached image, you'll see that it accepts anything from 100 to 240 volts AC and puts out either 32v DC or 12v DC.  The power supply connects to the printer's mobo with a 3-pin molex connector, and its pin config is diagrammed on the label (top right corner).  It shows both voltages being delivered on the right pin, ground on the middle pin, and a crescent (sleep mode?) on the left pin.

This would make sense to me if each voltage was delivered on a separate pin, but I wasn't aware you could have more than one on a single pin, which apparently is the case here.  When I meter the pins, I get 32.5v across right pin and ground (middle).  I get 30.3v across the right pin and the crescent (left) pin.  I get 2.2v across the crescent (left) and ground (middle). I don't get 12v anywhere.

Does this make sense to anybody, and if so, can you explain to me how it works?  I don't think I can declare my PS good or bad w/o first testing the 12v path to see what it reads, but how to I do that?

[image]

Thanks,
lunchbeast

Comment: I *think* that the third pin (left most) must be a control pin. Presumably when in sleep mode (hence crescent moon) the connected device will either pull this pin high or low to change the voltage down to 12V to save power.

Comment: Also, under no load the supply voltage will float up a bit, so it's not at all unreasonable to measure 32V rather than 30V - it's within 10% so I wouldn't be concerned with that.

Comment: I'd try connecting the left pin to ground with something like a 1k resistor (much less likely to cause damage than just shorting it with a wire if I am wrong about the function of the pin), and then see if it drops down to 12V. Also while you are at it, put a 1k resistor across the 30V/GND pins to act as a load and see if that helps it regulate to 30V properly.

Comment: PSU would be a more obvious abbreviation for power supply. When I read PS in association with a printer, I think postscript, and don't bother clicking through to the question...

Comment: I think Tom has it. To get 12V out, you need to do *something* with the Sleep pin, and only H-P know for sure what. But grounding it (via 1K for safety) is a reasonable first guess.

Comment: The printer electronics control the power supply mode through "sleep" pin (moon). Since the max. current on 32V is ~ 1A and on 12V 170mA, power supply delivers 32W on 32V and 2W on 12V.
So 12V must be the voltage in printer sleep mode.

What you need to do is measure the right pin (32/12V) when power supply is **connected** to printer. DC/DC power supplies do not get damaged when output is short-circuited or overloaded, that's why power supply is almost 100% ok.

Comment: What does "refuses to turn on" mean? Is there a standby LED and it is on in this case and printer does not respond to power button? If that's the case, most probably you have a problem with POWER BUTTON. Dirt and/or water is keeping it pressed constantly, solder (s) of the button are broken or the button itself is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Per testing on https://newscrewdriver.com/2019/04/03/hp-inkjet-printer-power-supply-for-nec-vsl0010-a-vfd/ the usage for a similar HP supply with the same labeling suggests that you simply ground the pin with moon symbol to switch the Voltage out pin from on/32V to standby/12V.

As Tom suggested in the comments, a small resistor of 1k or 4.7k or so is better than just shorting to ground.

Your supply may be different so take this as a general hint.

Comment: Its a mosfet  gate circuit, that receives a logic low for standby/12V   4.7K would be ok to use here.